# Why do Files and Disks applications show different values for free space?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

I encountered an issue with my Ubuntu partition's storage. Almost every disk checking app seem to show that its free space is around 29 GB, while Files and any other app shows that its free space is 12.7 GB. Anyway, it's…so unrealistic, like now Steam can only read 9,8 GB. Anyway I'm still researching this on my own. Anything you know or think?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Has anybody ever encountered anything like this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Please ask only one question per question. The two matters described are not related to eachother.

Comment: You'd be better to put an actual question in the question part. Rather than introduce it like a tweet or blog. "Why are different disk sizes shown?" for example.

Answer (score 4):

Partly you're seeing the difference between GiB (GibiByte) and GB (GigaByte).

- 1 GB is defined as 1000³ (1,000,000,000) bytes.
- 1 GiB as 1024³ (1,073,741,824) bytes.

So:

- 1 GB = 0.93 GiB.

That explains one discrepancy. The other is because the raw formatted size of the partition does not mean actual disk space. There's some overhead in the formatting of a partition for tables, block sizes etc. The different applications are mostly showing different things.